# PHP Send POST data to rewritten URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, post, url-rewriting

I have a page I'm developing located at `mysite.com/page`

On this page, the user can enter a username and password:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='username'>Username</label>
        <input class='form-control' id='spreadsheet-form-username' name='username' placeholder='Username'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='password'>Password (optional - required to edit)</label>
        <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' id='spreadsheet-form-password' placeholder='Password'>
    </div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the user clicks submit, it POSTs the data and the URL is rewritten to `mysite.com/page/exampleUser` or the equivalent of `mysite.com/page?username=exampleUser`

If the user only submits a username to lookup, I want them to only be able to view the data at `mysite.com/page/exampleUser`, and if they submit a correct password as well, they can edit the data.

I can get the correct URL, but I'm struggling in finding how to check if the username and password were both sent (and what their values are) on the `mysite.com/page/exampleUser` page. I want to be able to tell whether or not they should be allowed to edit the data on that page or not.

I tried this code:

```
$mode = "view";

if (isset($_POST["password"])) {
    if (hashOfPassword matches password submitted) {
        $mode = "edit";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    header("Location: /spreadsheet/" . $username);
}
```

but I can't seem to be able to get the $_POST["password"] data while at the rewritten URL. It's only available before the URL is rewritten.

I don't necessarily need to be able to send the password, but I would like to be able to send some bit of information letting me know whether the page should be viewable or editable. I also cannot send it via the URL (example: `mysite.com/page/exampleUser/edit`) since I don't want users to be able to edit other users' data simply by changing the URL.

Here's how I am dealing with url rewrites:

```
// Trim leading slashes
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

// Split url on slashes
$elements = explode('/', $path);

if ($elements[0] == "page" && sizeof($elements) == 1) {
    // do nothing, there wasn't a username submitted    
} 
else {

    switch(array_shift($elements))
    {
        case 'page':
            echo "username: " . $elements[1];
            echo "password: " /* not sure what to put here*/;
            break;
        default:
            header("/404.php");
            break;
    }   
}
```

and my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You could start a `session`, confirm the password before the URL rewrite and give the session some kind of 'authorization' that is then checked after the URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the password and some kind of identifier in the session. In the example below I used a `uniqid()` to generate a key. You can safely put this ID in the redirect URL.

Later you can check the ID and use the password stored in the session if it matches.

```
// Remove if session is already started at this point
session_start();
$mode = "view";

if (isset($_POST["password"])) {
    if (hashOfPassword matches password submitted) {
        $mode = "edit";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $passwordId = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['spreadsheetPasswordId'] = $passwordId;
    // Password should be hashed before writing it to session.
    $_SESSION['spreadsheetPassword'] = $_POST["password"]; 

    header("Location: /spreadsheet/" . $username . "/" . $passwordId);
}
```

and later

```
// Remove if session is already started at this point
session_start();
// Trim leading slashes
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

// Split url on slashes
$elements = explode('/', $path);

// we need at least three elements
if ($elements[0] == "page" && sizeof($elements) < 3) {
    // do nothing, there wasn't a username submitted    
} 
else {

    switch(array_shift($elements))
    {
        case 'page':
            echo "username: " . $elements[1];
            echo "password: " . (
                $_SESSION['spreadsheetPasswordId'] == $elements[2] ?
                $_SESSION['spreadsheetPassword'] : 
                'Access key is invalid or has expired.');
            break;
        default:
            header("/404.php");
            break;
    }   
}
```